# R - Link row values to create an ID column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
a  1  4  d  e
f  2  5  i  j
k  3  6  n  o
```

I would like to create an ID column based on row values such that:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 ID
a  1  4  d  e  a14de
f  2  5  i  j  f25ij
k  3  6  n  o  k36no
```

Is there a way to do so?

> Some variables are character and some numeric.

Comment: data$ID <- do.call(paste0, data)

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `paste` to create the 'ID'

```
df1$ID <- do.call(paste0, df1)
```